# SyntaxError: Unexpected token export in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

My understanding is that we can use ES6 standard on the node js, if we install the node module - Babel. Below are my dependencies on package.json

```
    "dependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4"
    }
```

**testFunction.js**

```
    export const fnc = () => {
        return "test";
    }
```

**index.js**

```
    const test = require("./testFunction");
    console.log(test);
```

Basically, I just want to import the user defined function on my index.js. But getting below error message:

> (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { export
>   const fnc = () => {
>                                                                 ^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
>       at new Script (vm.js:51:7)
>       at createScript (vm.js:138:10)
>       at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:199:10)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:624:28)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:573:32)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to compile your project. Installing babel is not enough. Personally I dont find compiling worth it in node.js. Its useful just for client side

Comment: Note that Node.js supports ECMAScript Modules natively. To distinguish between files containing Node Modules and files containing ECMAScript Modules, the latter need to be named `.mjs`. There is no need to use Babel for ECMAScript Modules, only if you want to use features of ECMAScript that are not supported by Node.js.

Comment: @JörgWMittag That feature is still experimental, right? https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html

Comment: @Rashomon: You're right. I thought it had already landed. So, read my entire comment above in the future tense.

Comment: @JörgWMittag haha, good to know anyway :)